# SQL MyISAM, reset auto increment for new inserts only

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, myisam

So we have a really big database table that holds important data for a limited amount of time.
The problem is that the table is never truncated completely, and the auto-increment id value is reaching 9 digits, which somehow needs to be reset in the near future.
We really need to reset it without truncating the current data, and rows currently in the table need to keep the same id value.
So f.ex the record with id '12345679' needs to keep id '123456789' in the database, but after a reset the next new insert should get id '1' and then '2' and so on. It will not be any collision between these new low values and the old values, but i don't know how to reset the auto increment value in this way.

Comment: How did you get into this problem?  Are the IDs used by any other tables?  If not, why have the ID?  Give us a hint of what kind of data is involved.

Comment: How do you determine which rows to `DELETE`?  This _may_ lead into `PARTITIONing`.

Comment: The id's are used by other software, the entries are used for a kind of transaction. When a new transaction is requested, it creates a new entry with data of that transaction, later the transaction is verified/completed. Every hour a script logs stats on the completed transactions and stores that as a single entry in another database, then removes all those entries from the database. incomplete transactions may linger in the system for up to a week and it's never truncated.

Comment: In making a 'transaction', are any ids wasted?  If so, by what means (such as using `REPLACE`)?  How big is the table (GB)?  Another likely problem (due to MyISAM) is 'fragmentation'.

Comment: If the ids were renumbered, would it hurt the 'other software'?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible:

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value is
>   less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and
>   the current sequence value is not changed.
>
> (Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

What you can do is create a new table and insert new data into it. Then create a VIEW that will return a UNION of these two tables.
For example, let's say your current table is called `myData`:

- rename `myData` to `myData_Original`
- create a new table name `myData_New` (with the same structure)
- create a VIEW named `myData`

`myData` view:

```
CREATE VIEW myData
AS 
SELECT *
FROM myData_New
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM myData_Original
;
```